# Obtaining the physical surface area of a character

Tags: char, ascii-art

I'm working on a script for ASCII art generation. The issue I've encountered has to do with what characters to use for the different shades of the image. I'm wondering if there is any resource that provides information on this.

For example, `"%"`takes up more space on the screen than `"."` so I would use `"%"` for darker regions of the image and `"."` for lighter regions.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following set of characters to cater for 16 different grey intensity:

`pattern:array [0..15] of char = ('#','#','@','@','%','%',';',';','*','*',',',',','.','.',' ',' ');`

To display white space character on HTML page, you can use `&nbsp;`